# TIBCO Enterprise 3.0 Architecture

Tags: java, tibco, orchestration

I'am a Sofware Engineer with many years of experience (20+). Currently I need to work with TIBCO which I don't know. I am being asked to get all the 4 following certifications. I will have available for studyng 4 hours per day during 1 year.

```
BW611: TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorksTM 5.x Integration Boot Camp
EMS11: Fundamentals of TIBCO Enterprise Message Service
BPM401: Developing Business Processes with TIBCO Business StudioTM 3.5.x
ARC701: Fundamentals of TIBCO Enterprise 3.0 Architecture
```

**Do you think this is possible (1 year VS 4 certifications)?**

Please remember that I don't know anything about TIBCO (is it difficult, easy, not well documented...?). However, I am a java certified specialyst is that helpful?

Regards,

Comment: Probably the wrong exchange to ask this question. See programmers stackexchange instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing Java is absolutely recommended !

*1 year for getting these 4 certifications is impossible* due to the following information:

From TIBCO website:

**BW611: TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorksTM 5.x Integration Boot Camp:**

Recommended General Experience

One year Enterprise Application Integration development experience, have an understanding of concepts such as distributed computing, adapters, services and canonical data model, exposure to Message Oriented Middleware, Java and other relevant technologies: XML, XPath, HTTP, JMS, SOAP, JDBC and Web Services.

**ARC701: Fundamentals of TIBCO Enterprise 3.0 Architecture**

Product Specific Experience

Candidates should have at least:
Two years experience designing message-based distributed systems using TIBCO products.
One year of hands-on experience with TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks, TIBCO ActiveMatrix Service Bus and TIBCO ActiveMatrix Service Grid.
One year of active experience using TIBCO products delivering successful composite applications and services projects.

Apparently, these two certifications doesn't exists any more:

**EMS11: Fundamentals of TIBCO Enterprise Message Service**

**BPM401: Developing Business Processes with TIBCO Business StudioTM 3.5.x**

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Java it is best to have some XML knowledge as you will mostly deal with XML/XPath mapping. If you want to use extensive java code you better should start doing that right-away. You "van" integrate "special purpose" code in BW process but you will not be able to debug into your java code so you really should why you can't do that using XML/XPath mappings. There are particular areas (very special formatting, hash maps instead of shared vars, ...) but try to keep them small.